# form registeration using an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mobile

Is there a way in iOS app programming that I can make an user fill up a form for registration? I mean do we have a template for that available already? Also I wanted to know that does it support something like EDIT where in if a user makes a typo then the fields along with checkboxes get auto-populated and one can update a required field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a framework for providing forms in-app:

http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ibaforms

As for the autocorrect thing, that is a customizable property of most, if not all, of the default iOS text-entry fields.

Comment: Thanks but I dont want auto-correct I want some idea on a way that I coul auto-populate the entries.

Comment: Plists are your friend.  Maybe keep an internal list of those fields you could auto complete and the string to auto complete them.  Then, while the user is typing, display maybe a UIMenuController containing the values... Wow, that's intense